# convert the alternate characters of the string to upper case . The first letter of the string has to be Capital

Tags: java

WAP to convert the alternate characters of the string to upper case . The first letter of the string has to be Capital.
 I/P:We are the worlD
 O/P: We ArE tHe WoRlD

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  Give it a shot and come back if you have a problem, and ask a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first letter is upper case, we conclude that every letter of the string at even position will be made to upper  case, but since there may be spece or special characters we will have to keep that in mind also. A sample algorithm you can use is:

```
String x = jTextField1.getText();
len = x.length();
String otherstring;
int j=0; //to be used as counter to check alternate char
for (int i = 0;i<len;i++) {
    j++;
    char ch = x.charAt(i);
    if(!isalpha(ch)){
        j--; //not to consider non-letters
        otherString += ch;
    }
    if (j % 2 != 0) {
        Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        otherString += ch;
    }
    else{
        Character.toUpperCase(ch);
        otherString += ch;
    }
}
```

the characters are appended to the other string and you can display the output.

Comment: hi its very helpful to find out the answer . thank you

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    String s="We are the worLD";
    System.out.println(s);
    int j=0;
    String otherstring=null;
    int length=s.length();
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        j++;
        char ch=s.charAt(i);
        if(!Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){
            j--;
            otherstring+=ch;
        }
        if(j%2==0){
            ch=Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            otherstring+=ch;                
        }else{
            ch=Character.toUpperCase(ch);
            otherstring+=ch;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(otherstring.substring(4));
```

}

Comment: This way i found the exact solution.